# How do I use custom exception in Java? I've followed the steps but am not getting my catch clauses to work

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I've been spending hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my java exception handling. I've followed all the books and sites in creating customs exceptions, throwing them, and attempting to catch them. They're extending RuntimeException (because they're thrown in an ActionEvent) so I don't think the throws clause needs to be declared in the method header. But the catch clauses won't run. Here's the pertinent code:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event){
        Object selectedButton = event.getSource();
        if (selectedButton == b1)
        {
            String passwordStr1 = password1.getText(); 
            String passwordStr2 = password2.getText();
            {
                if(passwordStr1.equals(passwordStr2))
                {

                if(PasswordCheckerUtility.isValidPassword(passwordStr1)== true)
                    {
                        Alert validAlert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        validAlert.setTitle("Password Status");
                        validAlert.setHeaderText("Password is valid");
                        validAlert.showAndWait();
                    }


              else
                try
                {
                    throw new UnmatchedException("The passwords do not match");
                }
                catch(UnmatchedException ue) {
                    Alert unEAlert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
                    unEAlert.setTitle("Password Status");
                    unEAlert.setContentText(ue.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```

and

```
public class UnmatchedException extends RuntimeException{

    public UnmatchedException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you missing `unEAlert.showAndWait()` in the catch block?

Comment: You say "the catch clauses won't run"; have you done any debugging to confirm whether or not this is true?

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle that's exactly right

Comment: @Jayson, `that's exactly right` - how have you done any debugging? I don't see any debug code in your "else statement", so how do you even know that code is getting executed? Post your [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. I include an "MCVE" in the edit to my answer. You code looks reasonable, but we don't know the context of how your code works. So simplify your code an post an "MCVE if you still have problems.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a more basic example and it seemed to work. Perhaps the issue is with some other aspect of your code. Here's what I used:

A main method:

```
public static void main(String...args){
    handle(null);
}//main()
```

The handle method:

```
public static void handle(ActionEvent event){
    try {
        throw new UnmatchedException("The passwords do not match");
    } catch(UnmatchedException ue) {
        System.out.println(ue.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And the custom exception in a separate class:

```
public class UnmatchedException extends RuntimeException{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UnmatchedException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you would throw/catch the Exception in the same method.

Exception processing is relatively expensive and should be avoided if possible. In your simple example you are just attempting to display an Alert message. That could easily be done in the "else statement".

I would typically only throw the Exception when you want the code that invoked the method to handle the Exception.

In any case throwing and catching the Exception in the same method works fine for me:

```
public class ExceptionTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        validate("hello there");
        validate("bye");
    }

    public static void validate(String text)
    {
        if (text.length() > 7)
            System.out.println("everythings good");
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if (text.length() < 8)
                    throw new StringTooShortException("Must be at least 8 characters");
            }
            catch (StringTooShortException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    static class StringTooShortException extends RuntimeException
    {
        public StringTooShortException(String message)
        {
            super(message);
        }
    }
}
```

When learning a new concept it is easier to start with simple code and get it working and then apply the knowledge to your real application. This problem is likely caused by your validation logic.

Comment: Exceptions in Java need to be caught OR declared, not both.  Declaring the exception in the method header does nothing.  If the exception is both caught and handled within the method, you do not need to declare it in the header.

Comment: @pseudobbs, I did not suggest to handle the Exception in the method. I don't see the point of catching an Exception. Exception generate overhead.  If you want to generate the Alert, then just do in in the else statement. If you really want to throw the Exception then I believe you need to declare in in the method header?

Comment: If the exception is caught in the same scope it is thrown, you do not need to declare it.  If the exception is caught by a method calling the method that throws the exception, then you need to declare it.  OP's question was about exception handling, not generating an Alert